# error for open the sqlite database with android studio

Tags: java, android, ios, database, sqlite

Can i know why when i run this project it was out this error and the app on device was unfortunely,app has stopped.the error is . android.database.sqlite.SQLiteCantOpenDatabaseException: unknown error (code 14): Could not open database

```
package dijkstra.app.com.demodistancev8;

import java.io.FileOutputStream;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.io.OutputStream;

import android.content.Context;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteException;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteOpenHelper;
import android.util.Log;
import android.widget.Toast;

//http://cariprogram.blogspot.com

public class SQLHelper extends SQLiteOpenHelper{

private static final String DATABASE_NAME = "schoolnav.sqlite";
private static final int DATABASE_VERSION = 1;
private static String DB_PATH = "/data/data/com.app.dijkstra/databases/";
private Context myContext;

public SQLHelper(Context context) {
    super(context, DATABASE_NAME, null, DATABASE_VERSION);
    // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
    myContext=context;
}

public void createDataBase() throws IOException{
    if(DataBaseisExist()){
        //do nothing - database already exist
        Toast.makeText(myContext, "Database Sudah Ada", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }
    else{
        //By calling this method and empty database will be created into the default system path
           //of your application so we are gonna be able to overwrite that database with our database.
        this.getReadableDatabase();

        try {
            copyDataBase();
            Toast.makeText(myContext, "Database Berhasil Diimport Dari Assets", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            throw new Error("Error copying database");
        }
    }

}

private boolean DataBaseisExist(){
    SQLiteDatabase checkDB = null;
    try{
        String myPath = DB_PATH + DATABASE_NAME;
        checkDB = SQLiteDatabase.openDatabase(myPath, null, SQLiteDatabase.OPEN_READONLY);

    }catch(SQLiteException e){
        //database does't exist yet.
    }
    if(checkDB != null){
        checkDB.close();
    }
    if(checkDB != null )return true ;else return false;
}

private void copyDataBase() throws IOException{
    //Open your local db as the input stream
    InputStream myInput = myContext.getAssets().open(DATABASE_NAME);
    // Path to the just created empty db
    String outFileName = DB_PATH + DATABASE_NAME;
    //Open the empty db as the output stream
    OutputStream myOutput = new FileOutputStream(outFileName);
    //transfer bytes from the inputfile to the outputfile
    byte[] buffer = new byte[1024];
    int length;
    while ((length = myInput.read(buffer))>0){
        myOutput.write(buffer, 0, length);
    }
    //Close the streams
    myOutput.flush();
    myOutput.close();
    myInput.close();
}

@Override
public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {

}

@Override
public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int newVersion) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

}
}}


<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
```

```
<permission android:name="dijkstra.app.com.demodistancev8.permission.MAPS_RECEIVE"
    android:protectionLevel="signature"></permission>
<uses-permission android:name="dijkstra.app.com.demodistancev8.permission.MAPS_RECEIVE"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
<uses-permission     android:name="com.google.android.providers.gsf.permission.READ_GSERVICES" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_PHONE_STATE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.SEND_SMS" />
<!--
The ACCESS_COARSE/FINE_LOCATION permissions are not required to use
     Google Maps Android API v2, but are recommended.
-->
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />

<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
    <meta-data
        android:name="com.google.android.gms.version"
        android:value="@integer/google_play_services_version" />

    <meta-data
        android:name="com.google.android.maps.v2.API_KEY"
        android:value="@string/google_maps_key" />

    <activity
        android:name=".MapsActivity"
        android:label="@string/title_activity_maps" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
</application>

</manifest>
```

Comment: i use android studio for build this project

Comment: you shouldn't fixed DB_PATH as that. instead you can build DB_PATH at runtime to get extractly your app data path .

Comment: @GiapLee can you teach me what can i need to correct?

Comment: you can try code in my answer

Comment: why would you give a hardcoded path to it?? It has no use for it

Answer (score 0):

For safely copy data from asset to app data folder, you can try this code:

```
String appDataDir = ContextWrapper.getFilesDir();

String copyDBPath = appDataDir + "/" + DATABASE_NAME;
```

Answer (score 0):

just don't use a hardcoded path, my sqlite works without a path.
my code :

```
public class PoiDbOpenHelper extends SQLiteOpenHelper {

    private static final int DATABASE_VERSION = 4;
    private static final String DATABASE_NAME = "pois.db";

    public static final String TABLE_POI = "tblpoi";
    public static final String TABLE_SQLITE_SEQUENCE = "sqlite_sequence";

    public static final String COLUMN_ID = "_id";
    public static final String COLUMN_LAT = "latitude";
    public static final String COLUMN_LNG = "longitude";
    public static final String COLUMN_NAME = "name";
    public static final String COLUMN_CITY = "city";

    public static final String CREATE_TABLE_POI = "create table "
            + TABLE_POI + "("
            + COLUMN_ID + " integer primary key autoincrement, "
            + COLUMN_LAT + " real not null, "
            + COLUMN_LNG + " real not null, "
            + COLUMN_NAME + " text not null, "
            + COLUMN_CITY + " text not null "
            + ");";
    ...
```